# Inside iOS method a dictionary's values not being set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dictionary

Ive got the following code:

Trying to debug it for a while. Can't figure it out.

```
    [self.vManager vendorsNearLocation:userLocation block:^(NSArray *vendors, NSError   *error)
     {
         self.vManager.vendors_array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:vendors];
         NSLog(@"Vendors array was %d long", [self.vManager.vendors_array count]);
         if(vendors && [vendors count])
         {
             for (id v in vendors)
             {
                 Vendor *aVendor = [[Vendor alloc] initWithAttributes:v];
                 [self.mapView addAnnotation:aVendor];
                 [self.vManager.vendor_dict setObject:aVendor
                                              forKey:[aVendor name]];
```

I was hoping to set the values of the dictionary in that loop. But dictionary is always empty. No errors or warnings, nothing gets set Yet the array has values and my map shows all the vendors. By the way the vManager is a Singleton and Dictionary is being initialized in the viewDidLoad method of the caller

Is there something that Im doing thats obviously wrong?

Comment: Have you properly initialised the dictionary?

Comment: Yes its being done in the view didload method like this-----self.vManager.vendor_dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];

Comment: Check if the the initialization is getting called before it executes the above method. If that is fine, then check the value of [aVendor name] is a proper string or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to initialize the dictionary in the SINGLETON class itself. I tried the same thing yesterday and it worked.

Just make a function and initialize the dictionary there and call that function before making use of that dictionary.

It will surely work.